# Internal doors not closing completely

Tags: doors, woodworking, door-frame

I have a pair of internal doors that have somehow been installed incorrectly.

[image]

The doors are too tight against the stops and this prevents them from closing all the way.

[image]

The options I see to fix this are:

1. Remove and rehang the doors, moving the screws just a couple of mm away from the stop. I'm not sure how to tackle this, I assume the screw holes would be refilled somehow and drilled with new holes just offset from where the original ones were.

[image]

2. Shave some wood off the stop. This seems easier but I'm not sure of the best approach. I could sand by hand, use a belt sander, some type of plane. Not sure.

[image]

Any guidance from people more experienced with doors would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It looks like attempting to close both doors causes the doors to hit each other in the middle, which means that the doors are too wide for the opening they're installed in. Are you saying that attempting to close just one door causes the door to hit the jamb and it won't move to the fully closed position, even if the other door is wide open?

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, the doors don't hit each other in the middle, it looks like that's happening on one of my pics as they have an overlapping section where they come together (like a half lap joint).  The doors won't close individually, even if the other is fully open and out of the way. The problem the doors hit the jamb (I was calling this the stop perhaps wrongly) as shown in my second pic.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the hinges used are original to the door. It also looks like the hinges are sized for cabinet doors normally a thinner door than a standard interior door.

I would change the hinges to [3X3 butt hinges](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X4BHJF9) and start from scratch. It will let all new holes drilled, more durable hinges used, and will give you the way to make the correction you need.

The hinge in the link is only an example, it can be a different finish or from a different supplier. The are many many different companies making this kind of hinge.

If you are content with the hinges you have, I would not move out the hinge on the jamb. That would leave a gap from where the hinge used to be, maybe it is not a big deal, but I would set it slightly deeper on the door, no gap there to be seen.